# Cannot boot xv6 after adding some codes to the kernel

Tags: xv6

I only made a little bit changes to the xv6 kernel to support shared memory. After compiling, I cannot boot it under qemu. It just halts at "booting from the disk...". But I didn't do anything to the bootloader. Can somebody tell me what's wrong,please?
[xv6 cannot boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOIot.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific with what changes were made exactly.
Please include them here.